# Different json attributes for column data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table data in SQL Server 2017 as below,

| Team | Drivers | Wins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red Bull | Max Verstappen | Australia |
| Red Bull | Sergio Perez | Azerbaijan |
| Ferrari | Charles Leclerc | Spain |
| Ferrari | Carlos Sainz | Bahrain |

I need data in JSON format as below:

```
{
       "Team": [
                 "Red Bull"
               ],
       "Drivers": [
                 "Max Verstappen",
                 "Sergio Perez"
                  ],
       "Wins":    [
                 "Australia",
                 "Azerbaijan"
                  ]
,

       "Team": [
                 "Ferrari"
               ],
       "Drivers": [
                 "Charles Leclerc",
                 "Carlos Sainz"
                  ],
       "Wins":    [
                 "Spain",
                 "Bahrain"
                  ]
}
```

Please help me how I can do it?

Comment: Why can't you do it? What's stopping you?

Comment: The format you have given is JSON - not XML and doesn't seem to make sense. If Team is a separate array how are members of that team tied to it in the JSON

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: what happens if you have another row with Team: ferrari? It's a bit unclear how the data should be grouped, please improve your example

Comment: Sorry guys...I wrongly added it as xml.It should be json format.

If we get one more row for ferrari then it will have seperate array.

Comment: I think something happened to your formatting. Also, shouldn't whole thing be inside an array?

Comment: Title still says XML.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a very good JSON data structure - relationships (particular between team members and where they won) are unclear.  But aside from that, what attempts have you already made to create a suitable query?  You should really show your own attempts first, so that others can assist you in where you might be going astray (rather than just asking for your work to be done for you)